# How to move project files of Android Studio from one computer to another. I have already published my app on google playstore and I want to update it

Tags: android, flutter

I have switched to my new computer and I want to run my old android studio project. My app is already published on Playstore and I want to update it. Updating an app requires keys (Keystore.jks) file. How can I create a new version of my existing app on my new computer to update it?

Answer (score 0):

Get the project started on the new machine (either manually copying or creating and cloning git repository).

Once you add it to the new machine. Just create the new APK referencing the new path for Keystore file (make sure you use the same Keystore from the old device, store in some location, and reference it in the local.properties file)

Answer (score 0):

Do you copy all file of project in old computer to new computer? Or do you use git?

If you want upgrade app, you upgrade version of app in pubspec.yaml file, and change file key.properties in folder android, in this file, your input correct path to your keystore.jks in new computer.

And last, run flutter build appbundle